# JavaScript's exponentiation operator works in Chrome but will choke Node?

Tags: javascript

The [exponential operator in JavaScript is documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)), and has the form:

```
  2 ** 3    // ==> 8, which is 2 to the power 3
```

but it works in Google Chrome, and choke Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

It's an ES7 feature, and only works in Node >7.

See: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/ for a complete list of browsers